# Where does the $node get its field values after a node edit page has been submitted?

Tags: entities

I'm attempting to debug a problem where a date field is not being saved.

The field renders fine with the rest of the node form, but upon submit one particular field has no value.

The `$form_state` contains the expected value all the way down until the form does a redirect to the node view, however, in `hook_node_presave`, all the data that should be on the node, is missing.

I'm getting lost in the form api trying to trace down where exactly the `form_state` gets added onto the node.

I am using Drupal 7, and the Date module version 7.x-2.5.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using and what version of the Date module or Date API are you using to create this date field? Also, can you describe more how the field loses its value? Does it happen while the submit is loading (i.e. some potential javascript is clearing the value) or does the resulting node lack the value entered into that field? Is this happening on node add or edit (or both)? What lead you to investigate form_state?

Comment: @sheena_d, I have accepted your edits, and updated question with some more info, but I reverted the title change as I would like the answer to be more generally applicable than just this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the actual work to attach the fields to entity objects is done in the [`_field_invoke()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/_field_invoke/7) function, right at the bottom with these lines:

```
if ($items !== array() || isset($entity->{$field_name}[$langcode])) {
  $entity->{$field_name}[$langcode] = $items;
}
```

That doesn't make a lot of sense out of context so it's worth having a look at the whole code for the function.

The basic workflow is:

1. The node form submit handler calls [`field_attach_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_submit/7)
2. `field_attach_submit()` calls [`_field_invoke_default()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/_field_invoke_default/7)
3. `_field_invoke_default()` calls `_field_invoke()`

The entity object is passed through all of those functions and once they're run all fields are attached to the object.

I know it's not much to go on but hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, unfortunately this is mostly what I've already found with the debugger, and it still eludes me what is happening >_<

Comment: Hmm that is a weird one :/ Turns out `date_field_presave()` (in date.field.inc) is responsible for actually adding the fields to the entity, maybe you could put a breakpoint in there to see if that function is for some reason being called after `hook_node_presave()` is invoked?